# Adding row means to matrix values over large dataset in R

Tags: r, matrix, row

I'm working with a large matrix (434728 rows, 394 columns).

I'd like to create a new matrix based on:

1. Taking all the elements in this matrix and adding the row means from another matrix of the same dimensions (`matrix_A[m,] + mean(matrix_B[m,]`).
2. Convert this outcome using the inverse logit in base 2 (`ilogit2()`).
3. Create a new matrix of the same dimensions as the first two.

I came up with a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(matrix)) {
   new <-(all.resid[i,]+mean(matrix[i,]))
   newb <-ilogit2(new)
   new.resid[i,] <-newb
}
```

And yes, it's really slow. How can I accomplish this task more efficiently?

Comment: I tend to believe `ilogit2` does maintain dimension and is vectorized. Then we can do `new=all.resid+rowMeans(matrix);newb=ilogit2(new)`

Comment: That looks like it works. And very simple. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Wow am glad it works.